# appendChild is not a function error (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have this piece

```
var inviteSection = document.getElementByClassName("invitedFriends");
var friend = document.createElement("div").class = "friend";

var mail = document.createElement("p").class = "mail";
var span = document.createElement("span").class = "status accepted";

function main() {
    inviteSection.appendChild(friend);

    friend.appendChild(mail);
    friend.appendChild(span);
}

main();
```

When I run this chrome console it says *'Uncaught TypeError: inviteSection.appendChild is not a function'* Is there any fix for this please help me guys!

Comment: `inviteSection` is a NodeList not a dom element reference

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`. Plural.

Comment: can you create a fiddle please ?

Comment: Note that *class* is a reserved word so you can't use it as an identifier, so the *class* attribute is reflected in the *className* property, so: `document.createElement("p").className = "mail"`. Also, where you have `var mail = document.createElement("p").class = "mail";` then the value of the variable *mail* is the string `"mail"`. Was that intended?

Comment: @ArunPJohny— *getElementsByClassName* returns an [*HTMLCollection*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), a special type of NodeList.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that, as [Akshay Arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763293/akshay-arora) points out, the method for getting elements by class name has to be plural. The implication is that it will always return an array-like collection of elements, even if it only finds one element with that class name. (This is what [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) meant by NodeList.)

If you're absolutely sure that there will only ever be the one element with that class name, then you just need to change the first line to

```
var inviteSection = document.getElementsByClassName("invitedFriends")[0];
```

If there is ever more than one element with this class name, this will just give you the first element.

Comment: Not an array, but an [*HTMLCollection*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), a special type of NodeList.

Comment: Well, you can't call any of the Array methods on it… ;-)

Comment: Again, true. But just like the `arguments` object in JavaScript, you can use most Array methods on it with `[].method.call()` and `[].method.apply()`.